# laravel return datatable add_column not work

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have a controller with method return the Datatables following

```
return Datatables::of($menu)
-> edit_column('name', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/project/\' . $id ) }}}" >{{$name}}</a>')
-> add_column('actions', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/photo/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm iframe" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  {{ Lang::get("admin/modal.edit") }}</a>')
-> make();
```

ajax script to retrieve data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",

            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('admin/menu/data/'.((isset($album))?$album->id:0)) }}",
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                $(".iframe").colorbox({
                    iframe: true,
                    width: "80%",
                    height: "80%",
                    onClosed: function () {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        var startPosition;
        var endPosition;
        $("#table tbody").sortable({
            cursor: "move",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                startPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length + 1;
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {
                endPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length + 1;
                var navigationList = "";
                $('#table #row').each(function (i) {
                    navigationList = navigationList + ',' + $(this).val();
                });
                $.getJSON("{{ URL::to('admin/menu/reorder') }}", {
                    list: navigationList
                }, function (data) {
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

the edit_column work but the add_column display nothing (also no errors), anyone know what the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->addColumn('actions', function ($menu) {
$test = '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/photo/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm iframe" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  {{ Lang::get("admin/modal.edit") }}</a>';
return $test;
})->make();
```

Comment: still display nothing, but when i access http://localhost/myapp/public/admin/menu/data/0, the action column shown as json

Comment: i think the response is ok, but the column (the responsed data) was not attached to the table

Comment: Have you shown `actions` columns in your blade file / related js file ?

Comment: no, i searched the "actions" in source code, nothing was found

Comment: i also can't find "actions" in json when i access localhost/myapp/public/admin/menu/data/0,